# .E01 and .EX01 format file Extraction

Tags: c#

I have one disk image (image) in my hand, I got it with forensic software. This image extension can be .dd .raw or .e01. When I want to view the contents of this image with the Filestream System.IO options, I get meaningless data. How can I make sense of this data? Thank you for the good work.An image contains information about any disk. For example, there is a copy of a C disk and all the files on the C disk. I want to access these files. However, I couldn't find a way.

Comment: The simplest way is to mount it as disk. What forensic software do you use?

Comment: I am trying to develop a software myself.

Comment: What software do you use to generate the image?

Comment: I am currently using FTK Imager. I will develop a software for creating images.

Comment: FTK Imager can mount the images. When you develop image creator you should also develop mounter.

Comment: Yes, you are right. However, I want to view images without mounting them with FTK Imager. I actually wrote a mount tool right now. I can see it with the mount. Any other chance to see it without mounting?

Comment: Yes, digging in to the filesystem you can create "sample browser". But will be pain in the bottom :D

Comment: :D I will do it somehow..